# Safe to store app signing key in source code?

Tags: github, google-play-services, google-play-console

For Google App Store requirements, I sign my app with a key store file. I generated that file using Java's keytool utility.  When I generate the keystore file, it asks me to provide/set a password.

I like to keep the build scripts and associated dependencies with the actual app/project. Can I safely store the generated in source control (github)? Since I had to provide a provide a password to generate the keystore file, **is the file sensitive for anything without also knowing the password**?

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is that you never store secrets in source code.  It's very common for source code to accidentally leak, and if that happens, an attacker can typically find that data very rapidly (because it's often of a specific form) and then attack it (i.e., try passwords) offline without you even knowing that it's compromised.  You might only find out that there was a problem when your program had been backdoored or something else terrible had happened.

It's much better to use a secure storage mechanism for that, such as a password manager (e.g., base64-encode it and store it in a 1Password secure note), a secret store (e.g., the secrets functionality of GitHub Actions), or somewhere else where it is properly secured (e.g., an encrypted backup).  Even simply storing it on your hard disk in another location would be fine, since it would be less likely to leak (although backups would be recommended).

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't feel like a "secret" file since it requires a password to do anything with?

Comment: Encrypted secrets are still secrets.  If it's a cryptographic key of any sort, encrypted or not, it's a secret.